# Why doesn't adding 24h worth of seconds to a Unix timestamp of right now give me the next day?

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

```
let todaySeconds = Date.now();
//1591238661657
let todayDate = new Date(todaySeconds);
//Thu Jun 04 2020 05:44:21 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time

//3600 * 24 = 86400s in a day
console.log(new Date(todaySeconds + 86400));
//Thu Jun 04 2020 05:45:48 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)
```

Why isn't the above Jun 05 2020?

Comment: Read the actual specification of the function before assuming you know what it does: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp

Comment: As always when working with dates, keep in mind that the [number of hours in a day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and [even the number of seconds in a minute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) is not guaranteed to be the same at any particular point in time

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript timestamps operate in milliseconds, not in seconds. You have to add `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.

```js
let todayMillis = Date.now();
let todayDate = new Date(todayMillis);

console.log(todayDate);
console.log(new Date(todayMillis + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming you are working with seconds. You are working with milliseconds. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

```
The static Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
```